# Toggle view/components for individual objects

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to imitate something similar to the ember todo guide where I can toggle between editing states, but using a component. If my controller is:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   isEditing: true,
   actions: {
      enableEditing: function(){
         this.set('isEditing', true)
      }

   }
})
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gosolora/1/edit

How do I toggle the editing state for only 1 item of the model at a time? Currently, clicking the edit button toggles the editing state for every item in the model.

Also, are there better alternatives to the `{{if isEditing}} {{else}} {{/if}}` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use an itemController which wraps each item in its very own controller.  Using an array controller, you can just define a property on the controller `itemController` and give it the name of the object controller to use.

#### Controllers

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'foo'
});

App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  isEditing: true,

  actions: {
    enableEditing: function(){
      console.log('editing on');
      this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    disableEditing: function(){
      console.log("editing off");
      this.set('isEditing', false);
    }
  }
});
```

#### Templates

Inside your template you will iterate the controller instead of the model

```
{{#each item in controller}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gosolora/2/edit

#### Tip

One last tip, if your action names don't match your action name in your hash, Ember will yell at you:

> Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'enableEdting'. If you did
>   handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an
>   action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

Comment: Just to bring up what I asked in original question, are there better alternatives to the `{{#if}} {{else}}` method?

Comment: if else is a perfectly acceptable method, the other possible method is making a child route for editing, and transitioning to that route with the model, it just depends on how complex of an editing form you are creating.